# Why does trying to parse this value result in a NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, exception

**Code**:

```
String myVar = "1255763710960";
int myTempVar=0;
try
{ 
   myTempVar = Integer.valueOf(myVar);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
{
    System.out.println(nfe.toString());
}
```

**Output**:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
For input string: "1255763710960"
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value you're trying to store is too big to fit in an integer. The **[maximum value for an Integer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)** is 2<sup>31</sup>-1, or about 2 billion. This number exceeds that by several orders of magnitude.

Try using a **[`Long`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)** and **[`parseLong()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29)** instead.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense now. Thanks for that, John! :)

Answer (score 4):

Java Integer maximun value  is 2^31-1=2147483647

You should use Long.valueof()

Comment: in addition to changing the type declaration of myTempVar

Answer (score 3):

Your String representation is too big (>Integer.MAX_VALUE) for parsing to an int. Try a long instead.

Answer (score 2):

1255763710960 is more than [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) which is 2147483647, so that value doesn't fit in an `int`.

You'll need to use a `long` and [`Long.valueOf()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) (or better yet [`Long.parseLong()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)) to avoid unnecessary auto-unboxing) to parse that value.